# How do I determine if an android device is naturally landscape or portrait?

Tags: android, accelerometer

How do I determine whether or not the accelerometer would report a roll of zero when the bottom **long** side of the screen is facing the ground?

I need to do this without instructing the user to hold the phone in a certain position.  I am hoping to be able to do something like:

```
Context.getResources().getConfiguration().getNaturalOrientation == Orientation.LANDSCAPE
```

**IMPORTANT: The above line of code is not possible, it's just an example of what I would like to do.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for this.  It's very simple using API8 and higher, simply use [Display.getRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

this may help you to detect the configuration change

```
 @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            //onConfigurationChanged
            if (newConfig.equals(Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)) {
                 //ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
            } else if (newConfig.equals(Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)) {
                 //ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
                }
        }
```

Comment: This might help, but it doesn't actually answer my question.  This tells me if the configuration changes.  I want to know if the device is "naturally" landscape or portrait.  That is to say, when the device is held in it natural orientation, is the long edge of the screen in the bottom or the short edge.

Comment: Based on what real-life pattern? Because Photoframes/Tablets are always Landscape and Phones portrait or do you just want to know what the phone orientation is RIGHT NOW, when you start your activity?

Comment: Some devices are naturally portrait, which means that when you examine the orientation sensors, pitch is -180 when when the device's top (short-edge because it is a naturally portrait devices) is facing up.  If it is a naturally landscape device, then pitch is reported as -180 when the top (long-edge) is facing up.  This may cause problems for apps that assume a certain roll value when the device is held in lanscape mode.  I think!